# Vector bundles can have transition functions on $O(k)$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I'm trying to prove that every smooth vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$ with rank $k$ can be given transition functions  $g_{\alpha\beta}: U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to GL(k)$ having values on the orthogonal group $O(k)$.

I know that we can define a metric $<\cdot,\cdot>$ on
$E$ and I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use it here, but I still don't know how.

I've tried to take each of local trivialization $\phi_\alpha:\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\to U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k$ and modify it a little so that $\phi_\alpha\circ \phi_\beta^{-1}$ would give rise to orthogonal transformations, but I got stuck, since we can have many  $\beta$s. Anyway, I couldn't find a way to use the global metric $<\cdot,\cdot>$, so I don't know where to go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **HINT**: Do you know how to give a (deformation) retraction $GL(n)\to O(n)$?  Think Gram-Schmidt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that on $E$ you can introduce an inner product. That is, there exists a family of $E_m$ for all $m$ such that for any two local lifts $v$, $w$
$$m \mapsto v(m), w(m)$$
is smooth. This uses a partition of unity. If $E$ is the tangent bundle of a manifold you get a Riemannian metric.

As an observation, it is essential to consider positive definite inner products. If we wanted another signature it may not work ( translation: not all vector bundles can be reduced to $O(k-l,l)$).

Once you do that, around every $x_i \in M$ take  $U_i$ of $B$ and 
$(u_{i1}, \ldots, u_{ik})$ a frame of the bundle. We may further reduce $U_i$ to $V_i$ so that $(v_{i1}, \ldots, v_{ik})$ can be Gram-Schmidt reduced to an orthonormal frame $(v_{i1}, \ldots, v_{ik})$. These will be our local frames. The fiber coordinate change on $V_i \cap V_j$ are given by smooth maps 
$$V_i \cap V_i \ni m \mapsto g_{ij}(m) \in O(k)$$

Comment: @AguirreK:          on each fiber it is a change of basis from an orthonormal basis to another.

Comment: Here is my confusion: the basis  $u_{i1}(m),..., u_{ik}(m)$ is sent (via local trivialization  $\phi_i$) to $(m, t^i_1),..., (m, t^i_k)$, where $t^i_1,...,t^i_k\in\mathbb{R}^k$. You're saying that the transformation  $\{t^i_1,...,t^i_k\}\mapsto \{t^j_1,...,t^j_k\}$ is orthogonal. I would agree with that if both $\{t^i_1,...,t^i_k\}$ and $\{t^j_1,...,t^j_k\}$ were orthonormal with respect to the canonical $<\cdot,\cdot>_{\mathbb{R}^k}$. But what we know is that they are orthonormal with respect to the inner product _induced_ by $<\cdot,\cdot>_E$, which is not the same thing, right?

Comment: @AguirreK: The definition of a basis is not the same as the definition of local trivialization of the bundle. They are what they are, in the fibre at each point. Do you think that a vector field on a manifold is a map from the manifold to  $\mathbb{R}^n$? You need to think of vector bundles in an intrinsic way.

Comment: @besides, there is no other inner product on the fibers except the one we defined. Are you familiar a bit with Riemannian metrics?

Comment: @Aguirre K: it is a bit confusing indeed. But think about a manifold and a point on it. Is that point an $n$-uple in $\mathbb{R}^n$?  Not really. Even a point on a sphere is not a pair of  numbers. The sphere has charts. Now for vector bundles, a frame will provide a trivialization. But it is not the trivialization. It's more like a dual thing, related but not the same. Like a particle and antiparticle.  well, I don't know if that is a good analogy.  And please be patient. Best to do some examples. Tangent bundles are good for that.

Comment: @Aguirre K: I did not understand then your question. I guess it's like this. Once we have a local basis $u_i$ then we have a local trivialization  $(m, (a_1, \ldots, a_k) )\mapsto (m, \sum a_s u_{i s}(m)$. Note that in this trivialization $u_{is}$ corresponds to the constant section $(m, e_s)$, for all $1\le s \le k$.

Comment: it really helped me to think about the tangent bundle. I was just getting lost with abstractions. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @AguirreK: You are welcome!  You can also think when it is possible to have the transition functions in $SO(k)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write a solution using my own words (credits to orangeskid):

For each trivialization $\phi_{\alpha}:\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\to U_\alpha\times \mathbb{R}^k$, let $\{s^\alpha_1,...,s^\alpha_k\}$ be a smooth frame in $U_\alpha$. Using Gram-Schmidt if necessary, we may assume $\{s^\alpha_1,...,s^\alpha_k\}$ is orthonormal with respect to the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_E$. If $\{e_1,...,e_k\}$ is the cannonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\phi_\alpha(s^\alpha_i(p))=(p,v^\alpha_i)$, there is a unique linear map $L_\alpha:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^k$ with $L_\alpha(v^\alpha_i)=e_i$.

Define a new trivialization $\psi_\alpha:=(id_{U_\alpha}\times L_\alpha)\circ\phi_\alpha$, which basically sends $s^\alpha_i(p)$ to $(p,e_i)$. That way, $\psi_\alpha\circ\psi_\beta^{-1}(p,v)=(p,M(v))$, where $M:=(\langle s^\alpha_i(p),s^\beta_j(p)\rangle_E)_{i,j}$, which is the change of basis from $\{s^\beta_1(p),...,s^\beta_k(p)\}$ to $\{s^\alpha_1(p),...,s^\alpha_k(p)\}$. Since both basis are orthonormal, $M\in O(k)$.$_\blacksquare$